# Unintentional port forwarding

Tags: port-forwarding

I had setup port forward from port 80 to 8082 some days back. My mistake - I don't remember how I set that up.

curl IP_ADDRESS //forwards to port 8082. Would like to remove this setting

curl localhost //doesn't forward to port 8082

OS Ubuntu 10.0.4 LTS
Any help would be highly appreciated. Its urgent.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Probably with `iptables`. Run `iptable-save` to check.

Comment: @bahamat It's web-server redirect(http redirect). iptables can't send redirect http.

Comment: @alvosu: maybe, but I would expect the webserver to redirect no matter which interface it was listening on. `iptables` is more likely to PAT only on specific interfaces. Thus "curl IP" redirects but "curl localhost". Localhost will be 127.0.0.1, but IP is probably the address assigned on the physical interface.

Answer (score 1):

Type in console:

```
  find /etc/ -type f -exec grep -i 8082 {} \; -print
```

then edit web-server config(apache,lighttpd,nginx).